# Scroll page to the nested React component on a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React Component with several nested components. For page navigation I have a few buttons on the top. 
The question is, how to scroll the page to the nested react component when a certain button is clicked, is it possible to do so without using jquery libs?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => { console.log('Scrolling to Item 1');}}>Button0</button>
        <button onClick={(e) => { console.log('Scrolling to Item 2');}}>Button1</button>
          <Layout>
            <Item>
              <Content>
            ...
              </Content>
            </Item>

            <Item>
              <Content>
            ...
              </Content>
            </Item>

          </Layout>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to scroll down to the element and React's [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get the DOM of your component.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/69z2wepo/67604/) is a small example that illustrates what you want to do.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
   alert("I will scroll now");

   this.refs.hello.scrollIntoView(); // scroll...
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div ref="hello">Hello {this.props.name}</div>; // reference your component
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using an anchor?

Put an id attribute ('myTarget') to your target component and replace the button with a link (href: '#mytarget').

This does not work with fixed headers, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a reference using useRef

   ```
   const trackButton = useRef();
   ```
2. Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method to scroll to the specific Element/ Component

   ```
       trackButton.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest" })
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Using React hooks and no 3rd party packages:

1. Create a reference using the React hook [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'
const firstItemRef = useRef(null);
```

2. Assign the reference to the component you want to scroll to

```js
<Item ref={firstItemRef}>
```

3. Use the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method to scroll to the specific Element/Component

```js
<button onClick={() => firstItemRef.current.scrollIntoView()}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using typescript.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component<{}> {
  private helloRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  public render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.helloRef}>Hello</div>
      <button onClick={() => { 
            if (this.helloRef && this.helloRef.current) {
              this.helloRef.current.scrollIntoView();
            } 
          }
      }>Button1</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get `scrollIntoView is not a function` errors. I have put in about 30 hours just trying to get one React element to scroll to another.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to implement it yourself, you can use [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)

Their [demo](http://fisshy.github.io/react-scroll-example/basic/index.html) is pretty much what you need.

Comment: where is the sourcecode of the demo you added? I cant find it in the official react-scroll github https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll

Comment: It's in the repository: https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/tree/master/examples/basic

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-scroll
`npm install react-scroll --save`

and for information can go to this page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll